# 64-bit ELF yielding unexplainable results

Tags: pointers, 64-bit, elf

Can someone explain why the following code yields different results on the second printf if I comment the first printf line or not, in **64 bits**?

```
/* gcc -O0 -o test test.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char a[20] = {0};
    char b = 'a';
    int count=-1;


    // printf("%.16llx %.16llx\n", a, &b);
    printf("%x\n", *(a+count));

return 0;
}
```

I get the following results for the second printf:

- commented: 0
- uncommented: 61

Thanks in advance!

*iansus*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain why the following code yields different results on the second printf if I comment the first printf line or not

Your program uses `a[-1]`, and thus exhibits undefined behavior. *Anything* can happen, and figuring out exactly why one or the other thing happenes is *pointless*.

The precise reason is that you are reading memory that gets written to by the first `printf` (when commented in).

I get a different result (which is expected with undefined behavior):

```
// with first `printf` commented out:
ffffffff

// with it commented in:
00007fffffffdd20 00007fffffffdd1b
ffffffff
```

You could see where that memory is written to by setting a GDB watchpoint on it:

```
(gdb) p a[-1]
$1 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) p &a[-1]
$2 = 0x7fffffffdd1f ""
(gdb) watch *(int*)0x7fffffffdd1f
Hardware watchpoint 4: *(int*)0x7fffffffdd1f
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 4: *(int*)0x7fffffffdd1f

Old value = 0
New value = 255
main () at t.c:12
12      printf("%.16llx %.16llx\n", a, &b);
```

It my case above, the value is written as part of initializing `count=-1`. That is, with my version of gcc, `count` is located just before `a[0]`. But this may depend on compiler version, exactly how this compiler was built, etc. etc.